# C++ lower_bound compare function issue

Tags: c++, stl, binary-search

I am having some issues with STL lower_bound function. I am new to c++. I needed to sort a vector of objects of class Biz, so I used this sort:

```
bool cmpID(const Biz & a, const Biz & b) {
    return a.bizTaxID < b.bizTaxID; 
}
sort(bussiness_list.begin(), bussiness_list.end(), cmpID);
```

The problem is when I try to find a object Biz by `bizTaxID` in another function with lower_bound. I thought I could use the same function `cmpID` for that, but obviously not:

```
taxID = itax; //function parameter, I am searching for the `Biz` with this ID
auto it = lower_bound(bussiness_list.begin(), bussiness_list.end(), taxID, cmpID);
```

I get a compiler error: 'bool (const Biz &,const Biz &)': cannot convert argument 2 from 'const std::string' to 'const Biz &'

I thought I could use the same compare fucntion for search as well as for sort. Can someone explain to me where is the mistake, and what exactly does `lower_bound` require from me to pass into? As I said, I am new to c++.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You comparison function takes `Biz` objects, while you are requiring a search over a `std::string` object (supposing `itax` is a `std::string`).

The easiest is to create a `Biz` object meants for the `lower_bound` call, something like that:

```
Biz searchObj;
searchObj.bizTaxID = itax;
auto it = lower_bound(bussiness_list.begin(), bussiness_list.end(), searchObj, cmpID);
```

Then compiler can use `cmpID` as it will try to compare `Biz` objects from your container to `Biz` object `searchObj`.

Alternatively, you could provide comparison operators to compare a `Biz` object with a `std::string`:

```
inline bool cmpID(const Biz& biz, const std::string& str) 
{
    return biz.bizTaxID < str; 
}

inline bool cmpID(const std::string& str, const Biz& biz) 
{
    return str < biz.bizTaxID; 
}
```

Also, I would recommend that you define C++ operators rather than functions, then, no need to pass the `cmpID` to all your functions (compiler will pick-up the good operator to be used):

```
inline bool operator<(const Biz & a, const Biz & b) 
{
    return a.bizTaxID < b.bizTaxID; 
}

inline bool operator<(const Biz& biz, const std::string& str) 
{
    return biz.bizTaxID < str; 
}

inline bool operator<(const std::string& str, const Biz& biz) 
{
    return str < biz.bizTaxID; 
}
```

Comment: @jpo38 Doesn't the approach with overloaded operators require support for the C++14 feature "Heterogeneous associative lookup" [(N3657)](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3657.htm)?

Comment: @marcbf: C++11 is enough I think.

Comment: @jpo38 Hmm... I can't get it to work with MSVC 2013 (yeah, we're still on that here ...for now). I get the same error as the OP. Currently, I'm using that hack where I use a lambda with a dummy for the second argument. I do like your method better, though, if only I could use it.